# extract a jpeg from a SMIL file

Tags: linux, perl, mms, hexdump

I am needing for my perl script to extract a jpeg from a SMIL file. The only way I have seen that does this is in linux is with the following command.

```
xxd -c1 -p wapenc\?T\=mavodi-6-13b-1f-4-7c-4806803 | tr "\n" " " | sed -n -e 's/.*\(ff d8 ff .*\)/\1/p' | xxd -r -p > image.jpeg
```

Wrapping it in a system() call does not work. What would be the proper way to incorporate such a series of commands into perl?

Comment: So far I am unable to get the commands to work. I get Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1. and Use of uninitialized value $/ in string ne at /usr/share/perl/5.20/B/Deparse.pm line 772.
-e syntax OK respectively. The copy of one of the smil files I am working with can be seen and downloaded here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2d64b2fab5eeada6f34c3cbc8b596fa720181217205049/1c30cd

Comment: The last command does not give me errors but the thumbnail.jpeg file that is creates does not appear to be a proper jpeg as it is only 206 bytes and is not viewable with Ristretto Image Viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing against the example file, I converted the oneliner from the comments to a proper script.

The meat of the script is the regex `/(\xff\xd8\xff.*?\x{ff}\x{d9})/s`, which extracts the start of a JPEG header until (and including) the end of the JPEG marker `\xff\xd9`, while still allowing for newlines etc. in it ( `/s` modifier ):

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

my( $filename ) = 'wapenc_T=mavodi-6-13b-1f-4-7c-4806803';
my( $outfilename ) = "$filename-thumbnail.jpeg";

open my $fh, '<:raw', $filename
    or die "Couldn't read '$filename': $!";
my $buffer;
{
    local $/;
    $buffer = <$fh>;
};

open my $output, '>:raw', $outfilename
    or die "Couldn't write to '$outfilename': $!";

if( $buffer =~ /(\xff\xd8\xff.*?\x{ff}\x{d9})/s ) {;
    print $output $1
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Maybe consider making it a perl module. Could not find anything that I though was suitable when I searched.

Comment: @gatorreina I'm not sure it makes sense to have JPEG extraction in arbitrary files, and I don't know anything about SMIL files in general...

Comment: @gatorreina BTW, maybe the question should be retitled to " perl script to extract a jpeg from a SMIL file" ? You could do that ...

Comment: While the above solution does work on some smil files it appears to not work on all -- while the original bash command does. For example, it does not extract the jpeg from this file https://wetransfer.com/downloads/70862c5b7e88937a07eba0ae4de05b8620181225191154/026f03 and truncates the jpeg to about 8% of the original file. I suspect that this may be due to a difference in the regex but am not sure. Still playing with it to try and make it work on all the files.

Comment: I believe that it might be because the regex appears to truncate after every instance of the magic number (ff d8 ff) and if the file contains the sequence more than once large sections are deleted. I believe the solution above might work if it were to keep everything after the first instance of the magic number sequence. Don't know enough about regex to test.

Answer (score 0):

Write the whole command to a temp file and execute that.

It will let you build the command in several statements if you like, which will make it more readable.

Or, better, run the first command in a readable pipe. Parse the data yourself, rather than farming it out in a bash pipeline to `tr` *and* `sed`, both of which are pretty weak compared to perl. Then direct the output through a writable popen.

Maybe you could even find a module that would let you handle what `xxd` is doing as well so that you don't need this at all. Maybe [Data::HexDump::XXD](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::HexDump::XXD)?

(haven't looked in detail, just trying to toss a quick, hopefully useful lead.)

Comment: The pipeline converts the file to a hexdump, munges the hexdump and then converts the hexdump back to a file. This is much better done in Perl directly by editing the file directly (resp. extracting from the file directly).

Comment: Yep. Totally agree.

Answer (score -1):

According to the jpeg standard there is a start of image and an end of image marker these are `OxFF OxD8` and `0xFF 0xD9` respectively.

So the following one liner should work

```
perl -0777 -wne '/(\x{FF}\x{D8}.*?\x{FF}\x{D9})/ and print $1' input.smil > thumbnail.jpeg
```

Comment: ... did you test that solution against the file linked in the comments? Also, you never populate `$_`, so you should copy that version from the comment as well.

Comment: Thanks but it gave me the following error: Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1. and created an empty jpeg file.

Comment: This answer fails if there are any newlines in the JPEG file, and never reads in the data.